# target all <a> loaded or not yet in onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a global way to get all my `<a>` in on.click ?

my code , it will be alot if do it like this .

```
  $("#menuMain-ul").on('click', '#collapsed-menu li a', function () {

    return false;
  });
```

something like this ?

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {

    return false;
  });
```

but it didt work for me , any other way i can target all my `<a>` ? i am using alot of ajax to get html content in return , so some contain `<a>` and i cant target in first place cause the `<a>` havet load yet.

**intention**

1.target all the `<a>`

2.have to also work after the `<a>` load by ajax

Comment: What does `but it didt work for me` mean?

Comment: it have no effect for the second code i tried.

Comment: What should your code doing inside the event handler? Can you reproduce it in an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you use this :

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: This seems like should work.  But sure about the Ajax case.  Out might have to be rerun on success of Ajax calls.

Comment: This will not work for `anchor` generated dynamically via ajax

Comment: @empiric - Why not ?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I assume there is a reason OP used [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for his event handler. The event handler will not bind on elements not existing in the DOM at the time it is executed

Comment: @empiric Thanks for that - it caused me to go and read the docs and learn a new thing.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat how do you generate html content its easy to add a  script tag that its content is like above code so the new html content now contain this event handler

Comment: if the scripts are at the end of the htm file ,this will  work!

Comment: wont work if the a call by ajax, are you sure farhadamjady ?

Comment: @deecheok yes I am sure but they should be handled in html content that comes from ajax

Comment: @farhadamjady so you suggest to add an event handler to the html that is loaded by ajax instead of using event delegation which is designed for this case?

Comment: so you mean i have to put the code in every html content that comes from ajax, will it cause problem ??? cause i have to add the code from the main page as well (which the page call the ajax )

Comment: yes I mean each page that comes from ajax @deecheok

Comment: @farhadamjady will it cause problem if i put in main page (which called the ajax) and the page return by ajax , both using the same code. will it have unknow bug ?

Comment: @farhadamjady thank you , i will give it a shoot. appreciate your advice , have a great day.